# Bootstrap navs problems (jumps up on click, mobile not rendering correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having the following bootstrap nav problems:

1) On desktop, when you click on each tab, it jumps up 1 pixel.

2) On mobile, the labels are all squished together (see attached photo)

3) Also on mobile, there is no space between each card when stacked

4) On desktop and mobile, the cards don't line up all the way to the left edge. You can see the "75 Results Found" text is where it should line up.

5) How do I text align the tab labels to the left (currently they are rendering in the center)

Here's my bootply:
http://www.bootply.com/nM8Q1MftKU

[image]

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="content-section-c">

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2>Sample Search Results</h2>
        </div>
    <div class="tabbable">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#pane1" data-toggle="tab">ELECTRONIC<br>APPLE TREES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pane2" data-toggle="tab">CROSSING GUARD<br>ORANGE TREES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pane3" data-toggle="tab">POLICE BODY<br>PEARS TREES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pane4" data-toggle="tab">PARKING METERS<br>&nbsp;</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pane4" data-toggle="tab">TRANSPORTATION<br>GRAPES TREES</a></li> 
                       </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="pane1" class="tab-pane active">
          <p class="results">126 Results Founds</p>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/01_card.png"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/02_card.png"></div>
         <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/03_card.png"></div>
         <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/04_card.png"></div> 
                                              </div>
        <div id="pane2" class="tab-pane">
        <p class="results">75 Results Founds</p>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/05_card.png"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/06_card.png"></div>
         <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/07_card.png"></div>
         <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/08_card.png"></div> 
        </div>
        <div id="pane3" class="tab-pane">
          <p class="results">144 Results Founds</p>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/09_card.png"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/10_card.png"></div>
         <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/11_card.png"></div>
         <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/12_card.png"></div> 
        </div>
        <div id="pane4" class="tab-pane">
          <p class="results">170 Results Founds</p>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/01_card.png"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/02_card.png"></div>
         <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/03_card.png"></div>
         <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/04_card.png"></div> 
        </div>
        <div id="pane5" class="tab-pane">
          <p class="results">256 Results Founds</p>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/01_card.png"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/02_card.png"></div>
         <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/03_card.png"></div>
         <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/04_card.png"></div> 
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.tab-content -->
    </div><!-- /.tabbable -->
    </div>

</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

Here's my css:

```
    .content-section-c {
    padding: 50px 0;
    background-color: #d4d4d4;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #3C5A78;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 0 0 16px 0;
}

.nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover{
 border-top: none;
 border-left: none;
 border-right: none;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #e9a39c;
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: #d4d4d4 !important; 
}

.nav-tabs>li>a:hover{
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover{
    background-color: #d4d4d4;
}

.nav-tabs{
    border-bottom: none;
    display: inline-block; /* needed to center the list items */
}

.tabbable{
     text-align: center;
}

.results {
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #355A78;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 20px 0 5px 0;
    text-align: left;
}

.nav-tabs {
    width: 100%
} 

.nav-tabs > li {
    width: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) In your css-code this line makes it jump up:

```
.nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #e9a39c;
}
```

2) The labels take 20% of the screen in your css-code:

```
.nav-tabs > li {
    width: 20%;
}
```

3) You have to overwrite the bootstrap.css code and you have to use media queries in your css-code.
Explanation of media queries:http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp
Add this to your css-code at the end of it, change **max-width** to what you want:

```
@media screen and (max-width : 640px){

    img.img-responsive {
    margin-top: 20px !important;
    }

}
```

4) You have to overwrite the bootstrap.css code
Add this to your css-code:

```
.col-md-6 {
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

5) Add a line to your css-code:

```
.nav-tabs {
    text-align:left;
    width: 100%
}
```